# ROS Answers SE migration: ompl error

Tags: ompl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros indigo

ubuntu 14.04 trusty

when i launch:

```
roslaunch clam_moveit_config move_group.launch
```

i get:

```
[ERROR] [1410255339.968987526]: Exception while loading planner 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner with base class type planning_interface::PlannerManager does not exist. Declared types are                               
Available plugins: 

[ WARN] [1410255340.750304310]: MoveGroup running was unable to load ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
```

contents of ompl_planning_pipeline.launch :

```
<launch>

  <!-- OMPL Plugin for MoveIt! -->
  <arg name="planning_plugin" value="ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner" />

  <!-- The request adapters (plugins) used when planning with OMPL. 
       ORDER MATTERS -->
  <arg name="planning_adapters" value="default_planner_request_adapters/AddTimeParameterization
                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixWorkspaceBounds
                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateBounds
                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateCollision
                       default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStatePathConstraints" />

  <arg name="start_state_max_bounds_error" value="0.1" />

  <param name="planning_plugin" value="$(arg planning_plugin)" />
  <param name="request_adapters" value="$(arg planning_adapters)" />
  <param name="start_state_max_bounds_error" value="$(arg start_state_max_bounds_error)" />

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find clam_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find clam_moveit_config)/config/ompl_planning.yaml"/>

</launch>
```

ompl_planning.yaml :

```
planner_configs:
  SBLkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::SBL
  LBKPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::LBKPIECE
  RRTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRT
  RRTConnectkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRTConnect
  LazyRRTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::LazyRRT
  ESTkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::EST
  KPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::KPIECE
  RRTStarkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::RRTstar
  BKPIECEkConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::BKPIECE
arm:
  planner_configs:
    - SBLkConfigDefault
    - LBKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - RRTkConfigDefault
    - RRTConnectkConfigDefault
    - ESTkConfigDefault
    - KPIECEkConfigDefault
    - BKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - RRTStarkConfigDefault
  projection_evaluator: joints(shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_pitch_joint)
  longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.05
gripper_group:
  planner_configs:
    - SBLkConfigDefault
    - LBKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - RRTkConfigDefault
    - RRTConnectkConfigDefault
    - ESTkConfigDefault
    - KPIECEkConfigDefault
    - BKPIECEkConfigDefault
    - RRTStarkConfigDefault
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192268/ompl-error/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did a ros-indigo-moveit-planners-ompl and it worked! thanks SaiHV.

---

Originally posted by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) with karma: 259 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like moveit is not able to find the planning plugins properly. How was moveit installed? Did you do a ros-indigo-moveit-full?

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1